# How to make td fill all row in a table without colspan

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a problem, this is my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9" style="text-align: center">Main Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <th>checkbox</th>
        <th>columna 1</th>
        <th>columna 2</th>
        <th>columna 3</th>
        <th>columna 4</th>
        <th>columna 5</th>
        <th>columna 6</th>
        <th>columna 7</th>
        <th>columna 8</th>
        <th>columna 9</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>coso 1</td>
        <td>coso 2</td>
        <td>coso 3</td>
        <td>coso 4</td>
        <td>coso 5</td>
        <td>coso 6</td>
        <td>coso 7</td>
        <td>coso 8</td>
        <td>coso 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>columna 1</th>
        <th>columna 2</th>
        <th>columna 3</th>
        <th>columna 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>coso 1</td>
        <td>coso 2</td>
        <td>coso 3</td>
        <td>coso 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using Bootstrap, the problem is that the fourth and fifth row are shorter than the others, what I want to do is that those td fill all the width without colspan, because the rows come from the server and I don't know how many come, I only know that the biggest amount of columns is 9, what I'm trying to do is fill all the width to not have white space at the right of the shorter rows.

Comment: Put them in a separate table, or don't use table.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use colspan? If we understand what the problem is, we may come up with a solution. The code currently does not have a problem. (Yes, some rows are shorter than others, but that is not a problem for a table!) So I presume this is an XY issue.

Comment: Put each header and rows in separate table, each table width 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to avoid colspan, so far i did not find the way but making colspan > max of columns that you could dynamically have, will do the trick, nothing will overflow.